# Detect td change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-selectors

edit: code below.

I am having a very strange issue where if you click in a table cell (td) that contains a button but don't actually click the button for some reason a bunch of nbsp's get inserted into the cell before or after the button which blows my table up. I am trying to write an event handler to take care of it but I can't seem to get the selector right because it is never triggering. So how would I create and event handler with the following requirements:

1. Trigger on change for all td elements that contain a button element
2. Once triggered replace all nbsp's in triggering td element with empty string ""
3. Must work with dynamic table built with angular repeats

Alternatively does anyone know of a way to just prevent the stupid nbsp's from appearing in the first place? Thanks!

```
<tr data-dir-paginate="item in postItemsDisplay | itemsPerPage: listItemsPerPage" data-total-items="totalItems" data-current-page="pagination.current">
    <td style="width:26px;">
        NBSP's SHOW UP HERE<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-ng-click="CopySingleItem(item.Id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>NBSP's SHOW UP HERE
    </td>
    <td><span data-ng-if="item.Attachments.results.length > 0"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-paperclip"></i>&nbsp;</span><a data-ng-attr-title="{{item.Title}}" onmouseover="javascript:this.style.cursor='pointer';" data-ng-click="SPModal(item.Id)">{{item.Title}}</a></td>
    <td>{{item.SingleText1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.SingleText2}}</td>
    <td>{{item.ChoiceColumnValue}}</td>
    <td style="width:26px;">
        NBSP's SHOW UP HERE<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-ng-click="DeleteConfirmation('TestList',item.Id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteConfirmation"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>NBSP's SHOW UP HERE
    </td>
</tr>

$scope.CopySingleItem = function (id) {
    $scope.currentItem = angular.copy(DataUtilitySvc.GetJsonByKey($scope.postItems, "Id", id));
    $scope.currTitle = $scope.currentItem.Title;
}
```

It's an IE problem because it only happens in IE 10 mode which unfortunately I have to support. It doesn't happen in edge mode but unfortunately other issues start happening in edge mode so I basically just have to pick and choose what to fix. I really hate IE.

Comment: Find the cause of the problem, don't try to fix it this way! Secondly, you'll have to add related code.

Comment: We're going to need the javascript code too, probably the code that contains the function for `CopySingleItem`

Comment: Added but it's not that. I don't think it is any of my code. It is some issue between some combination of IE 10 mode with angular on a sharepoint page. Like I said it doesn't exhibit this behavior in chrome or firefox or even IE in edge mode, but it does with IE in 10 mode.

Comment: So I found out where the problem was coming from. Apparently there are some uncaught errors in the SP.UI.Rte.debug.js file that are causing some strange behavior in IE. Does anyone know what this file really does? I am trying to find some documentation on it but so far information seems sparse.